# Simplifying an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify this expression ?

> $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{\frac{27a^6}{c^9}}{16b^3d \cdot 2d^4}}$$

First I remove the cube root and made it $( )^\frac{1}{3} $

But $16^\frac{1}{3}$does not give me a whole number .

Is there a way to simplify this , or is this expression impossible to simplify ? thanks for the help !

Comment: Simplify doesn't necessarily mean to get *everything* out of the radical. It means to get as much out as you can and to combine as many like terms as possible. You might not be able to get everything out but you can definately get most out. And you can get rid of that div sign and that times sign.  So it can *definitely* be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

As @fleablood wisely said in the comments, "simplify" does not mean to take everything out of the cubic root, just try to gather the terms and check which ones are pure cubes, and take them out of the cubic root:

> $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{\frac{27a^6}{c^9}}{16b^3d \cdot 2d^4}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{27a^6}{c^932b^3d^5}}=\frac{3a^2}{c^32bd} \cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{4d^2}}$$